# FactoryGirl associations make simple tests take 15 minutes +

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have tracked my incredibly slow tests down to my factories.rb file

```
FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :user do |f|
        f.sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com" }
        f.password "password"       
  end

    factory :character do |f|
        f.name "testcharone"
        f.race "human"
        user
    after(:create) { |character| character.init("fighter")}
  end
```

When I have the "user" association in my character factory, rspec tests invoking this factory will take more than 15 minutes to complete, but as soon as I remove the association, the same test is done within a second, even though the user association is never invoked in the tests. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Post the test that takes long to run (are you loading seed data?)

Comment: Turned out it was just my integration test that was slow, even though it was just a few visit this, click on that etc..